# Create a blank blogger template

Tags: themes, blogger

I am trying to create a blank blogger template. If i go to themes and edit html and paste the below code, i am getting the desired results. I am able to create a html layout element and get a homepage as i wanted but when when i create a new page the same homepage content is being copied and the new page content is not appearing. Now matter how many new posts or pages i create i get the same homepage. I am looking for a code which lets me create a new page with its own content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html b:version='2' class='v2' expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='https://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='https://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='https://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'> 
  <head>
    <meta content='IE=EmulateIE7' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'/> 
    <b:if cond='data:blog.isMobile'> 
      <meta content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0' name='viewport'/> 
    <b:else/> 
      <meta content='width=1100' name='viewport'/> 
    </b:if> 
    <b:include data='blog' name='all-head-content'/> 
    <title><data:blog.pageTitle/></title>
   <b:skin><![CDATA[/*
-----------------------------------------------
/////////// HTML THEME////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////TEMPLATE CREATED BY : FRINTON MADTHA////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////// DOWNLOAD FROM: www.FRINMASH.BLOGSPOT.com  //////////////////////////////////////////////////
----------------------------------------------
]]></b:skin>
   
  </head>
  <body>
   
    <center><h1> Blank Blogger Template </h1></center>
 

<!--Start Please keep the Credits intact-->
<div style='margin-top:300px; '> 
<center>
  <p class='author'>&#169; <b>Frinton Madtha Productions</b> Collaboration with<a href='https://frinmash.blogspot.com/'> FrinMash </a></p></center></div>


  <b:section class='navbar' id='navbar' maxwidgets='1' showaddelement='no'/>

<!-- End Please keep the Credits intact-->
  </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your blank template, there is no Widget defined as a Blog. There must be atleast one blog widget, right now you only have Navbar widget.

**Here is the modified code:**

I have only added this line, Blogger will parse it automatically and add the necessary Widget itself.

> <b:section id='main'/>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html b:version='2' class='v2' expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection'
    xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'
    xmlns:b='https://www.google.com/2005/gml/b'
    xmlns:data='https://www.google.com/2005/gml/data'
    xmlns:expr='https://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'>
    <head>
        <meta content='IE=EmulateIE7' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'/>
        <b:if cond='data:blog.isMobile'>
            <meta content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0' name='viewport'/>
            <b:else/>
            <meta content='width=1100' name='viewport'/>
        </b:if>
        <b:include data='blog' name='all-head-content'/>
        <title>
            <data:blog.pageTitle/>
        </title>
        <b:skin>
            <![CDATA[/*
-----------------------------------------------
/////////// HTML THEME////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////TEMPLATE CREATED BY : FRINTON MADTHA////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////// DOWNLOAD FROM: www.FRINMASH.BLOGSPOT.com  //////////////////////////////////////////////////
----------------------------------------------
]]>
        </b:skin>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <h1> Blank Blogger Template </h1>
        </center>
        <!--Start Please keep the Credits intact-->
        <div style='margin-top:300px; '>
            <center>
                <p class='author'>&#169; 
                    <b>Frinton Madtha Productions</b> Collaboration with
                    <a href='https://frinmash.blogspot.com/'> FrinMash </a>
                </p>
            </center>
        </div>
        <b:section class='navbar' id='navbar' maxwidgets='1' showaddelement='no'/>
        <b:section id='main'/>
        <!-- End Please keep the Credits intact-->
    </body>
</html>
```

if you are going to develop your own custom template, you can find a blank template from this Github repo.

https://github.com/jettheme/core/blob/main/blank.xml